# Debug DB2 stored proc

Tags: db2, toad

I am using IBM DB2 with Toad. I have a stored procedure that I need to debug.Any tutorial or videos on how to debug a stored procedure ? Echo statement won't work. One way would be to create a temp table, dump data in to it and open cursor at the end. But any alternative to this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't answer how to do this with Toad, but the (free) IBM Data Studio includes the ability to interactively debug stored procedures.  You can set breakpoints, step through your procedure, see variable values during execution, etc.

Comment: Any videos on how to debug an SP with Data Studio. I can find documentation on IBM website, but wasn't clear.

Comment: Before I posted the answer I did a quick look for any screencasts, but couldn't find any.  If you've used a debugger in any other IDE it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thanks. Will check it out myself